# Access Append Query In VBA From Multiple Sources Into One Table, Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, select, append, case

I hardly ever post for help and try to figure it out on my own, but now I’m stuck. I’m just trying to append data from multiple tables to one table. The source tables are data sets for each American State and the append query is the same for each State, except for a nested select script to pull from each State table. So I want to create a VBA script that references a smaller script for each state, rather than an entire append script for each state. I’m not sure if I should do a SELECT CASE, or FOR TO NEXT or FOR EACH NEXT or DO LOOP or something else.

Here’s what I have so far:

tblLicenses is a table that has the field LicenseState from which I could pull a list of the states.

---

```
Function StateScripts()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qryState As String
    Dim StateCode As String
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT LicenseState FROM tblLicenses GROUP BY LicenseState;")

'    and I've tried these, but they don't work

'    qryState = DLookup("LicenseState", "tblLicenses")

'    qryState = "SELECT LicenseState INTO Temp FROM tblLicenses GROUP BY LicenseState;"

'    DoCmd.RunSQL qryState


    Select Case qryState
        Case "CT"
            StateCode = "CT"
            StateScripts = " SELECT [LICENSE NO] AS StateLicense, [EXPIRATION DATE] AS dateexpired FROM CT "
        Case "AK"
            StateCode = "AK"
            StateScripts = " SELECT [LICENSE] AS StateLicense, [EXPIRATION] AS dateexpired FROM AK "
        Case "KS"
            StateCode = "KS"
            StateScripts = " SELECT [LicenseNum] AS StateLicense, [ExpDate] AS dateexpired FROM KS "
    End Select

    CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO TEST (  StLicense, OldExpDate, NewExpDate ) " _
         & " SELECT State.StateLicense as StLicense, DateExpire AS OldExpDate, State.dateexpired AS NewExpDate " _
         & " FROM ( " & StateScripts & " ) AS State " _
         & " RIGHT JOIN tblLicenses ON (State.StateLicense = tblLicenses.LicenseNum) " _
         & " GROUP BY  State.StateLicense, DateExpire, State.dateexpired " _
         & " HAVING (((LicenseNum) Like '*" & StateCode & "*') ; " 
End Function
```

Comment: Does `[DateExpire]` belong to `State` or `tblLicenses`?

Comment: A working select query joining the information from a single state and `tblLicenses` would also be helpful.  It would be much easier to start from a working query than to edit someone's edits.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are dealing with input sources that use different column names for the same information, and you are working to merge it all into a single table. I will make the assumption that you are dealing with 50 text files that are updated every so often.

Here is one way you could approach this project...

Use VBA to build a collection of file names (using `Dir()` in a specific folder). Then loop through the collection of file names, doing the following:

1. Add the file as a linked table using VBA, preserving the column names.
2. Loop through the columns in the `TableDef` object and set variables to the actual names of the columns. (See example code below)
3. Build a simple SQL statement to insert from the linked table into a single tables that lists all current license expiration dates.

Here is some example code on how you might approach this:

```
Public Sub Example()

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim strLic As String
    Dim strExp As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("tblLinked")

    ' Look up field names
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        Select Case fld.Name
            Case "LICENSE", "LICENSE NO", "License Num"
                strLic = fld.Name
            Case "EXPIRATION", "EXPIRATION DATE", "EXP"
                strExp = fld.Name
        End Select
    Next fld

    If strLic = "" Or strExp = "" Then
        MsgBox "Could not find field"
        Stop
    Else
        ' Build SQL to import data
        strSQL = "insert into tblCurrent ([State], [License],[Expiration]) " & _
            "select [State], [" & strLic & "], [" & strExp & "] from tblLinked"
        dbs.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If

End Sub
```

Now with your new table that has all the new data combined, you can build your more complex grouping query to produce your final output. I like this approach because I prefer to manage the more complex queries in the visual builder rather than in VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I came up with a variation of your idea:

I created table ("tblStateScripts"), from which the rs!(fields) contained the various column names

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim DB As Database

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tblStateScripts")


If Not rs.EOF Then
    Do
        CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO TEST (  StLicense, OldExpDate, NewExpDate ) " _
             & " SELECT State.StateLicense as StLicense, DateExpire AS OldExpDate, State.dateexpired AS NewExpDate " _
                    & " FROM ( SELECT " & rs!FldLicenseState & " AS StateLicense, " & rs!FldExpDate & " AS DateExp " & " FROM " & rs!TblState  " _
                    & " RIGHT JOIN tblLicenses ON (State.StateLicense = tblLicenses.VetLicense) " _
             & " GROUP BY  State.StateLicense, DateExpire, State.dateexpired " _
             & " HAVING (((LicenseNum) Like '*" & rs!StateCode & "*') ; "
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```